# Giving unique constraint to an non key attribute

Tags: c#, mysql

In my userprivilage table I have userId(auto increment), userName, password, and status columns. I want to provide unique constraint to userName column. so when I insert values to the table it should avoid the duplicate value of userName column. how can I do it? I'm using C# 2010 express windows application and mysql 5.1

Comment: At what level do you want to enforce the contraint?  DB? Business logic?  UI?

Comment: I think UI level is good for my scnario.. I'm inserting the values through textboxes... D Stanley

Answer (score 0):

If you're just writing plain SQL, you should be able to do it using the `UNIQUE` keyword. So, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE userprivilage
ADD UNIQUE (userName)
```

Comment: Thanx a lot even though I expect UI level I able to solve my problem using this sql query and some C# code... phillip-schmidt

Comment: @Jiya I could have added a UI level solution, too :P It'd just be a matter of searching for userNames before adding them